# Why is it legal to look at pending stock orders for some participants

Tags: united-states, tax-law, currency, shareholders

[another question](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/45638) indicates that market participants can take a look at the orders for a stock, option or futures. An ordinary investor can only look at the BID and ASK, but not the entire series of pending orders.

I am sure( feeling) that algorithms etc can take advantage of that. My question is why is that legal and what does these large specific participants provide in return ?

Comment: The premise of your question is wrong. Market depth (all pending orders) is freely available information.

Comment: @DaleM:  Getting that data, in real time, streamed at high-speed, is expensive.  This is a service that companies like [CBOE](https://www.cboe.com) provide and charge a lot for.

Comment: Why do you think information that is freely available has to be free?